# wso2DSS generate web services not working with parameters

Tags: web-services, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a wso2esb4.8.1 with features for wso2DSS. i have generate web service inthis url:
http://ec2-54-221-93-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9764/services/wsuaecd?tryit#
 this is the xml for the web service

```
<data name="wsuaecd" serviceNamespace="Wsuaecd">
<config id="default">
   <property name="carbon_datasource_name">UAECD</property>
</config>
<query id="select_with_key_bd_direccion_uaecd_query" useConfig="default">
   <sql>SELECT id_direccion, tipo_identificacion, identificacion, nombre_propietario, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, direccion_real, cod_barrio, nombre_barrio, cod_localidad, nombre_localidad, cod_upz, nombre_upz, cod_estrato, chip FROM public.bd_direccion_uaecd WHERE id_direccion=?</sql>
  <sql dialect="postgresql">SELECT id_direccion, tipo_identificacion, identificacion, nombre_propietario, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, direccion_real, cod_barrio, nombre_barrio, cod_localidad, nombre_localidad, cod_upz, nombre_upz, cod_estrato, chip FROM public.bd_direccion_uaecd WHERE id_direccion=?</sql>
  <result element="bd_direccion_uaecdCollection" rowName="bd_direccion_uaecd">
     <element column="id_direccion" name="id_direccion" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="tipo_identificacion" name="tipo_identificacion" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="identificacion" name="identificacion" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_propietario" name="nombre_propietario" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="primer_apellido" name="primer_apellido" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="segundo_apellido" name="segundo_apellido" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="direccion_real" name="direccion_real" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_barrio" name="cod_barrio" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_barrio" name="nombre_barrio" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_localidad" name="cod_localidad" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="nombre_localidad" name="nombre_localidad" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_upz" name="cod_upz" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_upz" name="nombre_upz" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_estrato" name="cod_estrato" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="chip" name="chip" xsdType="xs:string"/>
  </result>
   <param name="id_direccion" ordinal="1" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
  </query>
  <query id="select_all_bd_direccion_uaecd_query" useConfig="default">
  <sql>SELECT id_direccion, tipo_identificacion, identificacion, nombre_propietario, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, direccion_real, cod_barrio, nombre_barrio, cod_localidad, nombre_localidad, cod_upz, nombre_upz, cod_estrato, chip FROM public.bd_direccion_uaecd</sql>
  <properties>
     <property name="forceJDBCBatchRequests">false</property>
     <property name="maxRows">100</property>
  </properties>
  <sql dialect="postgresql">SELECT id_direccion, tipo_identificacion, identificacion, nombre_propietario, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, direccion_real, cod_barrio, nombre_barrio, cod_localidad, nombre_localidad, cod_upz, nombre_upz, cod_estrato, chip FROM public.bd_direccion_uaecd</sql>
  <result element="bd_direccion_uaecdCollection" rowName="bd_direccion_uaecd">
     <element column="id_direccion" name="id_direccion" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="tipo_identificacion" name="tipo_identificacion" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="identificacion" name="identificacion" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_propietario" name="nombre_propietario" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="primer_apellido" name="primer_apellido" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="segundo_apellido" name="segundo_apellido" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="direccion_real" name="direccion_real" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_barrio" name="cod_barrio" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_barrio" name="nombre_barrio" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_localidad" name="cod_localidad" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="nombre_localidad" name="nombre_localidad" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_upz" name="cod_upz" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="nombre_upz" name="nombre_upz" xsdType="xs:string"/>
     <element column="cod_estrato" name="cod_estrato" xsdType="xs:long"/>
     <element column="chip" name="chip" xsdType="xs:string"/>
  </result>
</query>
 <operation name="select_with_key_bd_direccion_uaecd_operation">
  <call-query href="select_with_key_bd_direccion_uaecd_query">
     <with-param name="id_direccion" query-param="id_direccion"/>
  </call-query>
 </operation>
 <operation name="select_all_bd_direccion_uaecd_operation">
  <call-query href="select_all_bd_direccion_uaecd_query"/>
 </operation>
 </data>
```

The response for the queries with parameters is:

```
<axis2ns104:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns104="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">DS Fault  Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param    name:id_direccion
</axis2ns104:DataServiceFault>
```

does anyone has thesame issue? ithink  is related with the configuration, but im pretty new  in wso2 .

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your question feels similiar to my question.

[Data Service fails when deployed with ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279286/data-service-fails-when-deployed-with-esb)

If our questions are the same then you will be able to solve your problem by simply using DSS and not ESB together.

Create an instance with DSS only and verify this resolves your issue.

Comment: I believe the problem is solved, all documented in my link above.